Conditionals with time clauses

I will help you while/when you doing your homework now

I will help you once/as soon as you are doing your homework now


I feel like 2 is wrong because "once or as soon as" imply that something is yet to happen so it doesn't make sense with "now" I don't really know what to think about 1?

separate error: "you doing" should be "you are doing"

Artur, Adam, Gregor, thomas, user203412 why do you continue posting the same type of questions? Why is the adverb "now" consistently in your examples? Several users have pointed out the misuse of it. I'm sure if you spent thirty minutes studying time clauses and conjunctions you would have a better understanding. You could then ask questions about specific examples you came across in text books and ask if they refer to repeated actions or single episodes.

There is no conditional in your question. And now would go here: I will help you now etc. Also, we use I'll most of the time.

once wants to be complemented by a clause using the perfect or the  simple tense indicating that an action has been completed or a condition has been met.  The word "now" shouldn't appear in such a clause; you are correct about that.

I will call you once the test results are available.
I will call you once the test results have been emailed to me.
I called him once the test results were available.
I called him once the test results had been emailed to me.

When I call, I can say something like this:

Now that the test results are available, I can tell you that you passed.


could you comment on my 2 examples

now doesn't work in either sentence.

In both cases now is unnecessary or downright wrong.

I will help you while you are doing your homework (probably implies that they are doing it now. But it would be more natural to say I will help you with your homework or to do your homework.)
I will help you when you do your homework (implies that they are not doing it yet).

Once and as soon as both imply the same as when.
